# Access Denied issue in AWS Glue while performing a simple ETL task

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am facing an error wile trying run AWS Glue , i am trying to copy data from my table which was filled with the help of a crawler.

The Error is given below

**An error occurred while calling o91.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 6YRCFCNCKW9ZK2PF; S3 Extended Request ID: 7v/5/dEhaxjIMMxfpCEu5vT6fwzmyV0kIphicPvUDYKY23rFYN1ALn2qo/N3CcIUEhSrOGKklW4=; Proxy: null)**

my script is given below :

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node AWS Glue Data Catalog
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1647583966899 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="s3-databse-mockdata",
    table_name="mock_data_csv",
    transformation_ctx="AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1647583966899",
)

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1647583976365 = glueContext.getSink(
    path="s3://destination-001/",
    connection_type="s3",
    updateBehavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
    partitionKeys=[],
    enableUpdateCatalog=True,
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1647583976365",
)
AmazonS3_node1647583976365.setCatalogInfo(
    catalogDatabase="s3-databse-mockdata", catalogTableName="dest-table"
)
AmazonS3_node1647583976365.setFormat("csv")
AmazonS3_node1647583976365.writeFrame(AWSGlueDataCatalog_node1647583966899)
job.commit()
```

I am unable to find what is the problem

Comment: What IAM role is attached to the Glue job?

Comment: you need to add s3 write permissions  to your IAM role

Comment: AmazonS3FullAccess

Comment: I tried with admin access and its running , but I think this is not correct